# My-Weather-Indicator has stopped working

Tags: my-weather-indicator

My-Weather-Indicator has stopped working after I filled in a second location although did fine before that. No Options - Settings are given at right click of mouse. Can someone please tell me how to repair it?

Answer (score 1):

- You can edit it's config:

  ```
  gedit ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf
  ```
- If you couldn't get it to work, delete it., it will create new one:

  ```
  rm ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf
  ```